# Where i can download Indian annual report XBRL files?

Tags: reporting, finance, xbrl

I tried a lot searching download XBRL report files (XML, iHtml, ixbrl or Instance file) for India MCA. I only can find out the information regarding XBRL. But none of talking about where to download publicly available annual reports files for companies in XBRL format.

If anyone know how i can get those files, would be great listen them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Annual Company Reports from MCA website http://www.mca.gov.in/ by Registering on their website and then per company you will have to pay Rs.100 to download the reports.

Do also check out https://www.99corporates.com in which 2.5 Million Indian Company Details can be viewed.

Comment: +1 You are right.. But these kind of public report should be available for free to use by public. Charging 100 INR/Doc, seems government are looting us.

Comment: yes you are right. do you found any way to get this for free. Do companies provide these type of reports on their websites.

Answer (score 0):

MCA is not providing the xbrl instance document. What it provides is pdf file of extracted information from xbrl instance document

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).